# Help, low render quality

Tags: cycles-render-engine

For the blend files in here https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1e9lWf9QMnpq8bB2CGxiwFD14scio8iBD
 I rendered using cycle render at 1080p but the render quality is low(other non obj file).  I used the yamato model inside.  In the user perspective object mode, you can see the waves and finer details, but in the avi clip, you can not.  Help! I need this for my class project

link:[image]

the avi file is very low res
[image]

Comment: Please don't make a question that depends on downloading a file exclusively. Use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question (https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and add more information, a precise description of the issue and images that illustrate it.

Comment: and, please use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to share .blend files (free, permanent, integrated) then edit your question and paste the provided link

Comment: which animation (avi file) resolution settings are you using?

Comment: With the lighting used on the screenshot it's hard to tell what's wrong could be there as object itself is barely visible. Proper lighting is one of the most important steps on doing good render. As to your multiple posts - please don't post the same question more than once. This will not guarantee an answer.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to setting your output image size to 100%
[image]

, you can also check your sample rate (also in the render section). Note that there are two sample options - for viewing and for rendering.

[image]

Have a play with different sample settings for rendering so that you are comfortable with how these impact on the level of detail. Of course, the more samples, the longer each render will take so it is a trade off between render time and render quality.

Lastly. **You have no lights on the scene**, you are lighting using only a flat color for the world, which will light the scene from all angles equally giving you the such ugly, flat, homogeneous lighting with no shadows. Add a light so that you can see shadows and those will help you reveal the shape of your objects.

[image]

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/46007/1853